# Writing a Sports League Program "The Django Way"

Tags: python, django

I'm coding for a large sports league in Django. I have separate tables for Sports, Teams, Schools, and Schedule. The Schedule model includes Home and Away Scores. This is a results-based app, not a scheduling one.

My question is on recording results "The Django Way". I could create a Results model that saves wins and losses, but that feels like storing unnecessary data, and could be a problem if two users submit different scores for the same game. The alternate way is to use a query and calculate wins/losses every time it's called up.

I'm up for the challenge, but am concerned that I'll start going towards a dead end. Here are my models, if that helps:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib import admin

class Sports(models.Model):
    sport = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    sport_name = models.CharField(max_length=225, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'sports'
    def __str__(self):
        return self.sport_name


class School(models.Model):
    school = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    school_name = models.CharField(max_length=225, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table= 'school'
    def __str__(self):
        return self.school_name

class SchoolAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ('school_id', 'school_name')

class Teams(models.Model):
    team = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    team_name = models.CharField(max_length=225, blank=True, null=True)
    sport_id = models.ForeignKey(Sports, models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
    division = models.CharField(max_length=225, blank=True, null=True)
    school = models.ForeignKey(School, models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'teams'
    def __str__(self):
        return self.team_name

class Schedule(models.Model):
    match = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    match_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    home = models.ForeignKey(Teams, related_name='home_set',  blank=True, null=True)
    away = models.ForeignKey(Teams, related_name='away_set', blank=True, null=True)
    home_score = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    away_score = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'schedule'
    def __str__(self):
        return '%s at %s' % (self.away, self.home)

class ScheduleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Schedule
    list_display = ('match_date', 'home', 'away', 'home_score', 'away_score')
```

Answer (score 0):

Create as many models as you need. If you only need the number of goals/points/score, then you can save it to a field on the Game model. If you need additional data about those goals/scores, then create a separate model for those. There really isn't a right or wrong answer to this - you just need to think about what you're gonna need. And also figure out what you might need in the future and how you can save all of that data. Create models according to your needs, not someone else's opinion.

I wrote an app for ice hockey some time ago and we had lots and lots of different models because we needed data about all of those. The main models for my app were Season, Referee, Game, GamePlayer, Player, GameReferee, Goal, Punishment, GamePunishment and GoalKeeper, but again - if you don't need all of that information, you don't need as much models either.